# $U$ is convex, $f\in H(U)$ and $|f'(z)-1|<1, \forall z\in U$ then $f $ is one-one function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

The hint is to use Fundamental theorem of calculus to the function, $1-(f'(z)-1)$. Can someone help me to solve this using this hint?

Comment: Use $f(x)-f(y) = \int_y^x f(t)dt$ and $|a-b| \ge |a|-|b|$.

Comment: $|a-1| < 1$ implies $\Re a >0$ so integrating $f'$ on the straight line joining $x,y$ (allowed since $U$ is convex which is crucial here) for any presumed $f(x)=f(y)$ should lead to a contradiction

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709866/42969.